# Зависает код на async/await Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Есть метод:

```
export const signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  const credentials = req.body;

  try {
    let user = await User.create(credentials);
    console.log(user); // выводиться пользователь, но код дальше не выполняется
  } catch ({ message }) {
    return next({
      status: 400,
      message
    });
  }

  return res.json(user);
};
```

Проблема в блоке try, пользователь создается но код дальше не выполняется, сервер как бы зависает, если пользователя еще раз создать, то код переходит в catch и возвращается ошибка, что пользователь с такими данными существует, то есть все работает, в чем может быть проблема ? Использую mongoose

Comment: может проблема в том, что в блоке `try` нет `return`? в `catch` он есть, поэтому скрипт продолжает работать дальше

Answer (score -1):

Проблема в том что user объявляется внутри блока try, нужно вынести его.

```
let user;

  try {
    user = await User.create(credentials);
  } catch ({ message }) {
    return next({
      status: 400,
      message
    });
  }
```

Comment: либо использовать `var`, либо перенести внешний return, внутрь `try`

Comment: Разве? Я вижу еще одну проблему - вместо return надо вызывать next.